# DAX dynamic RELATED function

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a data table connected to multiple lookup tables, and I'm trying to find a way to use a the RELATED function to fetch values from a dynamically-selected lookup table based on the values of one of the columns.

e.g.

If the `Month` column's value is `"2018_01"`, the `Type` column's value is `"Adjustment"`, and the `Variant` column's value is `"B"`, look in `'2018_01_Adjustment'[Var_B]` (essentially `'<Month>_<Type>'[Var_<variant>]`).

I was hoping DAX had some parallel to Excel's `INDIRECT`, but from looking through the internet, it appears it doesn't, so I need an alternative.

Comment: I found a workaround for part of the problem by combining some of the columns in each table into a reference key. The column references still require a SWITCH function. It's not as elegant a solution as I'd hoped for, but it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing using DAX is your [data model](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/data_modeling_with_dax/data_modeling_with_dax_overview.htm). 
For this type of question you need to model your data as thus:
First, do you have a date dimension? Once both the fact table (I think that's what you mean when you write "data table") have a link to the dimension table, you can link and group by the dimension you want, for example the MONTH or the YEAR.